# How to use ActiveAdmin on models using has_many through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, associations, activeadmin

I am using [ActiveAdmin](https://activeadmin.info/) gem in my project.

I have 2 models using has_many through association. The database schema looks exactly the same as the example in RailsGuide. [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)
[image: has_many through association]
<sub>(source: [rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/images/has_many_through.png))</sub>

How can I use ActiveAdmin to ...

1. show appointment date of each patient in physicians page?
2. edit appointment date of each patient in physicians page?

Thanks all. :)

Comment: what did you use to create that er diagram?

Comment: I didn't create that. I get it from Rails Guide website.

Comment: What we need to find out is what THEY used to create that diagram!

Comment: They used OmniGraffle, with this stencil:
http://www.diligentdesigner.com/2008/2/10/rails-diagramming-stencil-for-graffletopia

Answer (score 84, accepted):

For 1)

```
show do
  panel "Patients" do
    table_for physician.appointments do
      column "name" do |appointment|
        appointment.patient.name
      end
      column :appointment_date
    end
  end
end
```

For 2)

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Details" do # physician's fields
    f.input :name
  end

  f.has_many :appointments do |app_f|
    app_f.inputs "Appointments" do
      if !app_f.object.nil?
        # show the destroy checkbox only if it is an existing appointment
        # else, there's already dynamic JS to add / remove new appointments
        app_f.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => "Destroy?"
      end

      app_f.input :patient # it should automatically generate a drop-down select to choose from your existing patients
      app_f.input :appointment_date
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm doing a similar thing, but it ends up with a SQL nightmare. Each call to appointment.patient generates another SQL query.. standard n+1 query problem.

Has anyone found a way of doing the equivalent of ActiveRecord's eager loading? Eg .includes(:patient)

Comment: I have some trouble with your solution. The _destroy input won't work in my case

Comment: there could be many reasons and "won't work" isn't enough for me to know what exactly goes wrong. I am sorry about that.

Comment: *Quick Tip*: Make sure to include accepts_nested_attributes_for in the Patients model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments`

Comment: To anyone having similar issues to @Awea and being unable to destroy added items, ensure that `:allow_destroy` is enabled for nested  attributes, see [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699765/rails-3-paperclip-formtastic-deleting-image-attachments)

Comment: in case anyone is interested in the index page: http://www.eileenbuildswithrails.com/posts/has-many-relationships-in-activeadmin

Comment: Can we use the same with HABTM associations?

Comment: Will the approach allow update each appointment's data separately without a whole page reload?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ no, that code generates form fields for appointments, just a part of the whole form. So have to submit altogether.

Comment: Correction for 2) - it should be : `if !app_f.object.id.nil?`

Comment: In the case of using strong parameters, you should define the above in the active admin file.

Answer (score 15):

In answer tomblomfield follow up question in comments:

Try the following in your AA ActiveAdmin.register Model do block:

```
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      YourModel.includes(:add_your_includes_here)
    end
  end
```

This should lazy load all your associations for each index page in a separate query

HTH

Comment: `scoped_collection` is not called on the `show` view, so this won't solve tomblomfield's issue, since he was talking about N+1 queries on the `show` view. I'm running into this too, and haven't found a solution.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `def find_resource`, where you could run `Foo.includes(:bars).find(params[:id])`

Answer (score 1):

It should solve the N+1 query problem.

```
show do
  panel "Patients" do
    patients = physician.patients.includes(:appointments)
    table_for patients do
      column :name
      column :appointment_date { |patient|    patient.appointments.first.appointment_date }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's work for me (with chosen)

```
permit_params category_ids: []

form do |f|
   inputs 'Shop' do
     input :category_ids, collection: Category.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, as: :select, multiple: true, input_html: { class: "chosen-input",  style: "width: 700px;"}
    end
   f.actions
end
```

Comment: Replace `Category.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}` with `Category.pluck(:name, :id)` whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

@monfresh @tomblomfield you can do

```
has_many :appointments, ->{ includes(:patients) }, :through => :patients
```

in the physicians model

...or, I'm not sure if you can use it with formtastic but you could make the scope optional with something like

```
has_many :appointments :through => :patients do
  def with_patients
    includes(:patients)
  end
end
```

and `appointment.patient` wont n+1 anymore

Answer (score 0):

If you would like show multiple field in a panel row you can use following view:

```
show do |phy|
   panel "Details" do
        attributes_table do
          ... # Other fields come here
          row :appointment_dates do
            apps=""
            phy.appointments.all.each do |app|
              apps += app.patient.name + ":" + app.appoinment_date + ", "
            end
            apps.chomp(", ")
          end
        end      
   end
end
```

To place it in you redit form first put appointment_ids to permitted list:

```
permit_params: appointment_ids:[]
```

Add has many relationship to the form

```
form do |f|
   f.has_many :appointments do |app|
     app.inputs "Appointments" do
       app.input :patients, :as => :select, :label => "Assigned Patients"
       app.input :appointment_date
     end  
   end
end
```

Should work if there is no coding error.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding #2, it should be like this:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Physician Details' do
    f.input :name
  end

  f.inputs 'Physician Appointments' do
    f.has_many :appointments,
               heading: false,
               new_record: 'Add new appointment',
               remove_record: 'Delete appointment',
               allow_destroy: true do |app|
    app.input :patient, label: 'Choose the patient', collection: Patient.pluck(:name, :id)
    app.input :appointment_date
  end
end
```

Regarding the **heading:** - it can be false or some label (string)

Regarding the **allow_destroy:** - you can set it check for the user Administrator privilege's as can seen [here](https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html#nested-resources)

**Important** - In the Physician model, make sure to have

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments, allow_destroy: true
```

And, in the active admin model file - admin\physicians.rb - set this:

```
permit_params :name, appointments_attributes: [:patient_id, :_destroy, :id]
```