# ActiveAdmin forms with has_many - belongs_to relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I have the models Home and Photo, which have a has_many - belongs_to relationship (a polymorphic relationship, but I dont think that matters in this case). I am now setting up  active admin and I would like admins to be able to add photos to homes from the homes form.

The photos are managed by the CarrierWave gem, which I dont know if will make the problem easier or harder.

How can I include form fields for a different model in the Active Admin Home form? Any experience doing something like this?

```
class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true,
                     :length => { :maximum => 100 }
  validates :description, :presence => true      
  has_many :photos, :as => :photographable

end


class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :photographable, :polymorphic => true
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try something like this in app/admin/home.rb:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Details" do
    f.name
  end

  f.has_many :photos do |photo|
    photo.inputs "Photos" do
      photo.input :field_name 
      #repeat as necessary for all fields
    end
  end
end
```

Make sure to have this in your home model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
```

I modified this from another stack overflow question: [How to use ActiveAdmin on models using has_many through association?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099080/how-to-use-activeadmin-on-models-using-has-many-through-association)

Comment: Thanks man, but as soon as I use f.has_many I get an error: undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Maybe it has anything to do with the polymorphic association?

Comment: I tried using accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos in my Home model, but that doesnt work either.

Comment: Ok, I did that last part wrong the first time around, but that was the remaining problem, so maybe you should add it to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I also get the undefined method 'new_record?' for nil:NilClass error. How did you solved it @agente_secreto?

Comment: You need to add accepts_nested_attributes_for :children in your Parent model - that's how it solved

Comment: @agente_secreto I updated my solution with the accepts_nested_attributes call.

Comment: I had to do `f.input :name` rather than `f.name`.

Comment: Also need to add `f.actions` as the last item in the `form` block to get the 'Create' and 'Cancel' buttons

Comment: Will the engine allow to update each photo's data separately without a whole page reload?

Comment: if I have a set of images and I want to select the values from them, how can I do it using forms? ex: I have a product and several categories when I create a new product I should be able to add multiple categories from a predefined list of categories.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
form do |f|
  f.semantic_errors # shows errors on :base
  f.inputs          # builds an input field for every attribute

  f.inputs 'Photos' do
    f.has_many :photos, new_record: false do |p|
      p.input :field_name
      # or maybe even
      p.input :id, label: 'Photo Name', as: :select, collection: Photo.all
    end
  end

  f.actions         # adds the 'Submit' and 'Cancel' buttons  
end
```

Also, you can look at https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/5-forms.md (See *Nested Resources*)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for a form for a nested model. Take a look at following railscasts.

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
>
> http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

I cannot tell you much about active_admin, but I think this should not make a difference in handling the nested model.

Comment: Great, I will check them out, railscasts are always very useful

Answer (score 0):

I have a has_one model, like this:

```
f.has_many :addresses do |a|
  a.inputs "Address" do
    a.input :street  ... etc.
```

While this correctly reflects our associations for `Address` (which is a polymorphic model) using `f.has_one` fails.  So I changed over to `has_many` and all's well.  Except now we have to prevent our users from creating multiple addresses for the same entity.