# manipulating the h3 title with an activeadmin has_many form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099080/how-to-use-activeadmin-on-models-using-has-many-through-association) and was able to get set up a has_many form properly.

Here's where I'm at:

```
f.has_many :related_contents do |rc|
  rc.inputs "first configuration" do
    #...
  end
end
f.has_many :related_contents do |rc|
  rc.inputs "second configuration do
    #...
  end
end
```

so I want to have different configurations of fields.  What I can't figure out is how to set the `<h3>` that activeadmin generates and sets as the title for the nested fields.  I thought something like

```
f.has_many :related_contents, :title => "first set" do |rc|
```

would work, but It does not.  Does anybody know what I need to do to get this working right?

I assume that changing the `<h3>` will also change the button that gets generated to add. Is there another option I need to set for that as well?

Comment: I fixed it with javascript... but that seems like a hack. There should be a way to do this with activeadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('h3:contains("Related Contents")').hide().first().show();
```

Not perfect, but it definitely looks better.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `:heading` option to the `f.has_many` method

```
f.has_many :related_contents, :heading => "first set" do |rc|
  #...
end
```

To remove the heading altogether, set it to `false` or `nil`

Comment: This seems to be [a new addition](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) as of ActiveAdmin 0.6.1! Great tip!

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow the next order, i mean, you need to set on first line the "inputs" and then the "has_many" block, I hope this is what you are looking, regards!

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "details #1" do
    f.input :title, :label => "Title"
    f.input :description, :label => "Description"
    f.input :image, :as => :file, :required => false, :label=>'Image'  

  end

  f.inputs "details #2" do
   f.has_many :subdetails do |a|
       a.input :description, :label => "Description"
       a.input :image, :as => :file, :required => false, :label=>'Image'
   end  
 end
```

Ok, after have some problems with the title of has_many I could figure out how is the correct way for do it and i think is more cleaner and fancy...

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Post" do

      f.input :title
      f.input :description

    end

    f.inputs "Comments" do
     f.has_many :comments do |a|

        a.input :title
        a.input :description

      end  
    end

    f.buttons
end
```

Comment: this creates another bar with a name, and appears redundant visually on the page.  Not really what I was looking for.